# How to fix : "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to display a dynamic Google Bar Charts in Laravel using AJAX.

So, I'm trying to populate data in laravel using AJA with select option, and I get this error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

**My View**:: tstChart.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dynamic Bar Chart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMonthlyChart);
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawMonthlyChart(chart_data, chart_main_title) {
        let jsonData = chart_data;
        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Months');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Quantite');
        $.each(jsonData, (i, jsonData) => {
            let month = jsonData.month;
            let quantite = jsonData.quantite;
            data.addRows([
                    [month, quantite]
                ]);
            });
        // Set chart options
        var options = {
                       title:'Monthly Data',
                            hAxis:{
                                title: 'Months'
                            },
                        vAxis:{
                            title:'Quantite'
                        },
                        colors:['black'],
                        chartArea:{
                            width:'50%',
                            height:'80%'
                            }
                       };
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
      function load_monthly_data(year, title) {
            const temp_title = title + ' ' + year;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'chart/fetch_data',
                method:"post",
                data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                     year:year
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success:function(data) {
                    drawMonthlyChart(data, temp_title);
                } 
            });
            console.log(`Year: ${year}`);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="bg-secondary">
    <header class="text-center p-4 text-white bg-dark">
        <h1>Dynamic Bar Charts </h1>
    </header>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">         
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <select name="year" id="year" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Year</option>
                    @foreach($year_list as $row)
                        <option value="{{$row->year}}">{{$row->year}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                    {{-- <option value="2020">2020</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                    <option value="2018">2018</option> --}}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 150px;"></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 600px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" 
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#year').change(function() {
                var year = $(this).val();
                if(year != '') {
                   // alert(year);
                    load_monthly_data(year, 'Monthlly Data for:');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**My Controller**:: GraphController.php

```
    class GraphController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        $data['year_list'] = $this->fetch_year();
        return view('tstChart')->with($data);
    }
    public function fetch_year() {
        $data = DB::table('ventes')->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT YEAR(date) year'))
                //->groupBy('date')`enter code here`
              //  ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')
                ->get();
        return $data;
    }
    public function fetch_data(Request $request) {
        if($request->input('year'))
        {
         $chart_data = $this->fetch_chart_data($request->input('year'));
         foreach($chart_data->toArray() as $row)
         {      
          $output[] = array(
           'month'  => $row->month,
           'quantite' => $row->quantite
          );
         }
         echo json_encode($output);
        }
    }
    function fetch_chart_data($year)
    {
        $data =  DB::table('ventes')->select(DB::raw('DISTINCT id_vente, quantite, YEAR(date) year, 
                    MONTH(date) month'))
                                   // ->orderBy('year', 'ASC')
                                    ->where('YEAR(date)', $year)
                                    ->get();
           return $data;
      }}
```

**Route** :: Web.php

```
Route::get('/charts','GraphController@index');
Route::post('chart/fetch_data', 'GraphController@fetch_data');
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any sort of redirect set up, such as from HTTP -> HTTPS? You can check for redirects by watching the Network tab of your developer console.

Comment: Did you try php artisan route:clear ?

Or php artisan view:clear

php artisan config:cache

Comment: are you missing a `/` at the start of your post route?

Comment: thank you for your answers, unfortunately the problem has not yet solved

Comment: @BasmaLachhab can you open your network tab on your browser, and see the request that fails, show us the exact ful url it's trying to hit please